# Which certificate from Let's Encrypt does a website use for HTTPS?

Tags: linux, ssl, dropwizard, lets-encrypt

I have a website that was set up to use https using a certificate from Let's Encrypt. I am trying to add that certificate to a keystore to use https with a dropwizzard API. The problem I am having is that there are multiple certificates.

My question is how can I figure out which of the certificates my website uses so that I could use that for the API as well?

In `/etc/ssl/certs` this is what shows up:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      49 Nov 20  2017 ca-bundle.crt -> /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  885625 Apr 12 00:27 ca-bundle.crt.rpmnew
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      55 Nov 20  2017 ca-bundle.trust.crt -> /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl/ca-bundle.trust.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1059673 Apr 12 00:27 ca-bundle.trust.crt.rpmnew
-rw------- 1 root root    1586 Dec 15  2017 localhost.crt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     610 Aug 17 17:16 make-dummy-cert
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2516 Aug 17 17:16 Makefile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     829 Aug 17 17:16 renew-dummy-cert
```

Comment: You need to look at your webserver configuration files. They will list each certificate used by each virtual host. They will probably not be in that directory, since from your output nothing "intuitively" match a website certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking more closely at the config files like Patrick had suggested I found the config file in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` that had the path to where the certificate and private key were.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at your vhost file to see the path to the physical ssl cert files being used by the website. The vhost is likely going to be at /etc/apache2/sites-available/ .